# Ionic + Cordova InappBrowser - Input type=file not working

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

The app simply shows a webpage using `Cordova InAppBrowser`. The webpage uses 
`<input type=file>` to upload files.

When I open the webpage in chrome on my android device, the tap on input opens a menu that displays `camera` and `documents` options. But when same webpage is opened using `InAppBrowser` it does not show the menu.

I have tried `_self` and `_blank` options with InAppBrowser. I have also tried using crosswalk browser but no luck. 
`Cordova version 6.0.0`, `Android version 5.1.1` and I am using [this](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/inAppBrowser/) ngCordova plugin

Has anyone managed to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with Cordova InAppBrowser plugin.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9148